# Azure WebApp Config - Multiple VirtualApplications copyIndex not valid

Tags: azure, templates

While deploying WebApp ARM template in Azure, I am getting the following error:

> 'The template function 'copyIndex' is not expected at this location. The function can only be used in a resource with copy specified.'

```
   "resources":[
            {
                "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
                "name": "[concat(variables('webSiteName'),'/','web')]",
                "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
                "dependsOn": [
                  "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('webSiteName'))]"
                ],
                "properties": {
                "alwaysOn": "true",
                "copy": [
                    {
                        "name": "virtualApplications",
                        "count": "[length(parameters('virtualdirectories'))]",
                        "input": {
                            "virtualPath": "[parameters('virtualdirectories')[copyIndex('virtualApplications')].virtualpath]",
                            "physicalPath": "[parameters('virtualdirectories')[copyIndex('virtualApplications')].physicalpath]"
                        }
                    }
                ]
                }
```

My parameters file contains virtual directories..:

```
 "virtualdirectories": {
        "value": [
            {
                "virtualpath": "vd1",
                "physicalpath": "site\\pd1"
            },
            {
                "virtualpath": "vd2",
                "physicalpath": "site\\pd2"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Any idea whats wrong?